# Mockito.when() not working properly while mocking Autowired object

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a conrtoller class in which I am getting details regarding Currently logged in user. The method name is `LoggedInUser()`. The method is running perfectly in general, but I'm unable to produce unit test case for particular method.

For testing it, I am using Mockito but `Mockito.when()` is not working properly.
I went through all the related questions but not able to solve it.

Following is what I've done so far.

**Controller.java**

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    Public class Controller implements someInterface {

private LoggedInUser getUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
            principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
            Authentication tk = (Authentication) principal;
            //Authentication tk = (Authentication)(request.getUserPrincipal());
            LoggedInUser user = (LoggedInUser) tk.getPrincipal();
            return user;
        }
```

The line in comment is written because I read in another post that it may not work as 'principal' is instantiated again. So i tried to bypass it but that didn't work as well.

Test.java

```
@Mock
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

public void tes() {
        //httpServletRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        Principal principal= Mockito.mock(Principal.class);
        Mockito.when(httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);
.......
.......
}
```

While debugging, I am getting value for `request (object of HttpServletRequest)` as it's Autowired in controller class but `principal` is always null.
Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Uncomment the 1 line inside `tes()`

Comment: Your mock has not effect if the reference that you have to mock is not assigned with the value of the mock. You should show the code of the tested method.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ppasler Already tried...didn't work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to mock `HttpServletRequest` because it's `Autowired` and thereby `request.getUserPrincipal()` always remains Null as it never calls the `mock().when` method.
I replaced the code in following manner it worked!!

**Controller.java**

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    Public class Controller implements someInterface {

    public LoggedInUser getUser() {
        LoggedInUser user = (LoggedInUser )SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return user;
    }
```

**Test.java**

```
    @Mock
    private Principal principal;

    @Mock
    private SecurityContext securitycontext;

    @Mock
    private Authentication authentication;
     public void test() {
      LoggedInUser user = new LoggedInUser();
        Mockito.when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(user);
        Mockito.when(securitycontext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securitycontext);
.......
.......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you added `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` on this test class? Because only then `@Mock` will work. I am assuming you are passing on mocked `HttpServletRequest` to `getUser()`.

Comment: no. I've added 'MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)'

Comment: Yes, that will also init your mocks.

Comment: Can you provide the complete example.?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. But I can tell that after 'Mockito.when()', another function will be called; which calls the 'LoggedInUser()'.

Comment: From your comment on other answer its quite clear that HttpServletRequest is not mocked. As it is being Autowired to your controller, investigate around the way how it should be mocked. I will update if I finds something.

Comment: I've gone through link but couldn't find the solution. I went through other posts and I think may be the problem is either the returning object(`principal`) is also mocked or the `@transactional` annotation above the controller class. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have not injected your mocked object `httpServletRequest`. You need to pass this mocked object to your `getUser` method for testing.

Comment: and how exactly can i do that?

Comment: If your method was not private you could call `getUser(httpServletRequest)` after mocking it `httpServletRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);`. You need to see where this is passed to your Servlet

Comment: While debugging, I am getting value for `request (object of HttpServletRequest)` as it's Autowired in controller class but `principal` is always null.